# Split query to match a specific pattern - regex or parser?

Tags: java, regex

I'm working with API that does not allow in specific scenarios to use "OR" or "AND" in queries.
So I have to split the query(String) and send one by one which is fine but it has to be with three brackets at start and end of the string, which is causing me troubles.

So the string I have to split looks like this:

```
"WHERE (((City LIKE 'Japan') or (Id IN ('555666','666555, 88811888')))) LIMIT 10000"
```

API has built in methods that I have to use in order to send a query, above string should be separated in two and look like:

```
1. (((City LIKE 'Japan')))
2. (((Id IN ('555666','666555, 88811888'))))
```

I'm not very familiar with regex, but I did try to remove all brackets to get clean string without them and then just surround String with 3 brackets from each side, which is not working well for obviously example 2, it deletes the brackets that surround IDs. So I assume regex is not the best solution, but I'm not really sure how to properly create parser for this. Any help would be nice!

EDIT:
Example of code with regex that is removing brackets:

```
String condition = query.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","").replace("WHERE", "").trim();

return "(((" + condition + ")))";
```

Comment: `I did try`. Then show what you've done so far

Comment: Sorry if you did not understand, I did what I mentioned in the post, used regex to remove brackets and that works fine for example 1, but it does not work for example 2 because it removes brackets that are used for IN ( 'id1' , 'id2')....

example of code: 
`String condition = query.replaceAll("[\\[\\](){}]","").replace("WHERE", "").trim();
    return "(((" + condition + ")))"`;

Comment: I did understand. I just wanted you to show your regex that doesn't work correctly

Comment: I see, I've edited the post.

Comment: Depending on your query language proper parser may be better solution.  A while ago I didcustom language plugin for IntelliJ and found this tutorial useful:  https://jetbrains.org/intellij/sdk/docs/tutorials/custom_language_support/grammar_and_parser.html

Comment: You are putting too much on regex. There are simply too many corner-cases to occur in an SQL query. I would recommend using a parser as well.

Comment: actually this type of queries is pretty much the only query clients can do. The only problem with this scenario is that this specific API call(only this) does not allow queries with AND/OR conditions so I have to separate them. Other API endpoints allow AND/OR conditions. So this would make me have a parser for only 1 scenario that happens with only one client, few times in a month. Thought I would get it done with just splitting the query for that specific scenario.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In simple scenarios you can use following code:

```java
List<String> splitQuery(String input) {
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\({2}(.+)\\){2}").matcher(input);
    if (m.find()) {
        return Pattern.compile("(or|and)", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
                // Here m.group(1) extracts substring between "((" and "))"
                // Splitting m.group(1) by "(or|and)" gives you N tokens
                .splitAsStream(m.group(1))
                // And then you encapsulate each token in "((token))"
                .map(token -> "((" + token.trim() + "))")
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
    } else {
        return Collections.emptyList();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```java
List<String> result = splitQuery("WHERE (((City LIKE 'Japan') or (Id IN ('555666','666555, 88811888')))) LIMIT 10000");
result.forEach(System.out::println);
```

Output:

```
(((City LIKE 'Japan')))
(((Id IN ('555666','666555, 88811888'))))
```